# Does postmessage work in safari at all in 2022?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 sites, postmessage is cross-domain.
In chrome, everything is OK, the message is sent. Safari is not.
There is no specific information
Only except for the fact that this option seems to have been removed in new versions. Does anyone have information or maybe an example of a working postmessage for safari of our time?

Comment: The Browser support does exists for safari version 4 & 5. [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: "*the fact that this option seems to have been removed in new versions*" - where did you get this information?